# C++ program . The program should use recursion and looping

Tags: c++

Im trying to run a C++ program with binary output. Please help .

0000
0001
0010
0011
0101
0110
0111
1000
1111

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service, please show your efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one could be

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int i;

for(int i=1; i<10; i++){
    string binary = bitset<8>(i).to_string();
    cout << binary << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

8 is bitset here.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, thats exactly what i was looking for

Comment: Then Why don't you mark as Answer ? @Dupsey